# Ionic put delay on loading tabs

Tags: android, ionic-framework, angular-directive

in my tabs ionic app, I am trying to display use custom images as my icons for my tab items. To do so, I've found that I am supposed to provide a designated class for the tab items and render image via css styling.

However, upon testing on my two android devices, android api 21 and 16, I do not see these custom image icons in my tab items. They do display fine when I do `ionic serve` and they exist in my `root_path/platforms/android/assets/www/img`. Via chrome's inspect devices, I found that the images folder is not even loaded when the tab-item is trying to find these images to render.

[From this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-4-4-4-url-image-render-problem/9375/23), I found that ionic does some magic behind the scenes to load images when they do not load into the device. But it seems to only work for elements in `ion-view` or `ion-content` only and do not apply for the `ion-tabs` that's outside of it.

[I found here](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/uaKxw) that using a directive could provide a solution to this but it seems that it only works to put the directive on my `ion-nav-view` element in my `index.html`, which would not cover my `ion-tabs`?

So, are there any other way around? If not, how do I use my directive to check if my `ion-nav-view` contents are fully loaded before my `ion-tabs` contents gets loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

`tabs.html`

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-bottom tabs-color-active">
  <ion-tab title="Live" icon="tab-live energized" href="tab/live">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-live"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="Replay" icon="tab-replay energized" href="tab/replay">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-replay"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="Settings" icon="ion-android-options energized" href="tab/setting">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-setting"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

`index.html`

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar apricot">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

## UPDATE

I've worked around this issue by uploading my image to my `firebase` storage and loading the image for my tabs from there. But this only seems like a "temporal workaround" so if anyone's got the way to resolve it, please do help...